# what is the regular expression to match this url?

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I am running a scrapy project and i want to extract that text out of the response:

```
>>> response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').extract()
[u'<tr class="over"onclick="HM.set(\'bWFya2V0PT1nZW5lcmFsfHxzdD09MzB8fHN0cz09eyIxMCI6IlJlZ2lvbiIsIjIwIjoiTWlkZGxlIEVhc3QiLCIzMCI6IjRSVU5ORVIgNjcxMzYwIn18fGNhdGFsb2c9PTY3MTM2MHx8cmVjPT1CMw%3D%3D\');">\n<td>671360</td>\n<td>4RUNNER</td>\n<td>11/1995-11/2002</td>\n<td>KZN185,RZN18#,VZN18#</td>\n</tr>']
```

i need to extract:

`bWFya2V0PT1nZW5lcmFsfHxzdD09MzB8fHN0cz09eyIxMCI6IlJlZ2lvbiIsIjIwIjoiTWlkZGxlIEVhc3QiLCIzMCI6IjRSVU5ORVIgNjcxMzYwIn18fGNhdGFsb2c9PTY3MTM2MHx8cmVjPT1CMw%3D%3D`

i tried to use: `response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re('[^HM.+D$]*')`
,but the results was:

```
[u'<tr class="over" onclick="', u'', u'', u'', u"set('bWFya2V0PT1nZW5lcmFsf", u'', u'xzd', u'', u'09', u'', u'zB8f', u'', u'N0cz09eyIx', u'', u'CI6IlJlZ2lvbiIsIjIwIjoiTWlkZGxlIEVhc3QiLCIz', u'', u'CI6IjRSVU5ORVIgNjcx', u'', u'zYwIn18fGNhdGFsb2c9PTY3', u'', u'T', u'', u'2', u'', u'', u'x8cmVjPT1C', u'', u'w%3', u'', u'%3', u'', u'\');">\n                                    <td>671360</td>\n                                    <td>4RUNNER</td>\n                                    <td>11/1995-11/2002</td>\n                                    <td>KZN185,RZN18#,VZN18#</td>\n                               </tr>', u'']
```

Comment: You could try to at least get the `onclick` attribute. Also, that doesn't seem to be a URL, just a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

```
(?<=HM\.set\(')[^']+
```

So in your case, it would translate to:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re(r"(?<=HM\.set\(')[^']+")
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=HM\.set\(')` - Positive lookbehind to match the substring `HM.set('`.
- `[^']+` - Negated character class to match all non-`'` characters one or more times.

However, it would be more efficient to just use a capturing group for this.

For instance:

```
HM\.set\('([^']+)'
```

Which would be:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re(r"HM\.set\('([^']+)'")
```

---

Your expression, `[^HM.+D$]*` wasn't working because `[^]` is a negated character class, which means that all characters except `[HM.+D$]` will be matched (which isn't what you wanted).

As an alternative, you could always retrieve the `onclick` attribute and then parse the value out from there:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]/@onclick').re(r"HM\.set\('([^']+)'")
```

Comment: `>>> response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re('(?<=HM\.set\(\\')[^\\]+')
  File "<console>", line 1
    response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re('(?<=HM\.set\(\\')[^\\]+')
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
it cause an error.

Comment: `>>> response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re("‌​(?<=HM\.set\(\\')[^\‌​\]+")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 94, in re
    return flatten([x.re(regex) for x in self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 240, in re
    return extract_regex(regex, self.extract())
    regex = re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE)
error: unexpected end of regular expression`

Comment: @Hathout - That's an escaping issue... Try using a raw string by adding `r` before the expression... `response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re(r"‌​(?<=HM\.set\(\\')[^\‌​\]+")`

Comment: `>>> response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re(r‌​"‌​(?<=HM\.set\(\\')‌​[^\‌​\]+")
  File "<console>", line 1
    response.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tr/td/table/tr[2]').re(r‌​"‌​(?<=HM\.set\(\\')‌​[^\‌​\]+")
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Hathout - I downloaded scrapy to debug it. I updated my answer; did it work for you?